# code for how to perform calling and cancel the calling in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to developing iPhone applications.

I am looking for an example on calling phone numbers, specifically starting a call and ending one.

Is this possible ? If so, how would one accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to make a call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"tel:1-800-ACCE-PTME"]];
```

Anything that modifies a user's ability to block phone calls is going to run afoul of Apple's basic approach to third-party apps. There are a lot of things that are questionable and you might get away with. Blocking calls is clearly forbidden.

Comment: ok thanks for give me solution , but i am also require code for how to end the call. i uses this code for dail a number , but it pickup the default diaing through iphone , but i want to use it in over own application , i require calling and ending of call controlling in my hand through code.

Comment: Apple's implemented security that pauses all apps while a call is in progress. You cannot stop a call from coming in or terminating it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:374347347"]];
```

I don't think Apple allows you to cancel calls from within your app.